# Latex ignoring vspace. How do I get these two images on the same page?

Tags: spacing, pdf, graphics

I have the following to insert two images into a latex document:

```
\begin{center}
    \hspace*{-1in}
    \includegraphics[width=8.5in]{rmse.pdf}
    \vspace*{-2in}
    \hspace*{-1in}
    \includegraphics[width=8.5in]{mae.pdf}
\end{center}
```

This allows them to width across the width of the page perfectly, but the problem is I can't get them both on the same page. They would easily fit, except latex is insisting there be about 3 inches between them. I've tried a figure, subfigures and negative vspace* (which gets ignored).

Can anyone tell me a simple way to reduce the spacing/margins/whatever to get latex to realize they fit together?

Comment: In the title and the description you speak of `\vspace`, the code contains `\hspace`. Perhaps edit the question to make it less ambiguous.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- You could use [pdfcrop](http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfcrop) to crop the interfering margins off the two pdf files. This small tool could already be part of your LaTeX distribution.
- `\includegraphics` understands optional arguments for cropping the margins, you might use for instance `trim` or `viewport`.
- Macros like `\makebox`, `\llap` and `\rlap` could reduce the effective width of the image.

Comment: I didn't even think about the fact that the pdf itself would have margins. Thanks!